# View not updating when property is changed by event from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I am trying to run something like a background thread and notify a ViewModel of the status of this background thread by raising an event. The ViewModel in turn raises the OnPropertyChanged event. Unfortunately the corresponding view will not update.

The part of the background thread where I notify the ViewModel can be seen here:

```
private void RunThread() {
        while(true) {
            suspendEvent.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
            if (shutDownEvent.WaitOne(0)) {
                break;
            }
            if (pauseEvent.WaitOne(0)) {
                pauseEvent.Reset();
            }
            Notify("Cleaning started!");
            pauseEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            Clean();
            Notify("Cleaning finished!");
            pauseEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        }
    }

private void Notify( String status ) {
        NotifyOfCleanerStatusHandler handler = NotifyOfcleanerStatus;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(status);
        }
    }
```

The part of the ViewModel where I receive the event can be seen here:

```
public void SetCleanerStatus( String status ) {
        CleanerStatus = status; 
    }
```

And finally, the property that I bind my view to is seen here:

```
public String CleanerStatus {
        get {
            return cleanerStatus;
        }
        set {
            if (value != null) {
                cleanerStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CleanerStatus");
            }
        }
    }
```

The intriguing thing is: The View will show one of the above statuses, either "Cleaning started!" or "Cleaning finished!". One would think that they should alternate in an interval of 5 seconds. This is not the case.

If I remove the first waithandle call (pauseEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));) the message in the view is "Cleaning finished" and stays that way. If i keep the line, the message is "Cleaning started!" and stays that way. Debugging shows that the line OnPropertyChanged(..) is reached.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: very strange what you are doing why you want to update the property from another thread ViewModel shall working in the main thread?!

Comment: Does the handler goes to null at any moment?

Comment: I think your while lus gets breaked immediately Because the shutdownevent.waitone(0) returns without waiting. Check msdn: "If millisecondsTimeout is zero, the method does not block. It tests the state of the wait handle and returns immediately." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc189907(v=vs.110).aspx @ Remarks section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your RunThread method:

```
private ManualResetEvent suspendEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private bool shutdown;

private void RunThread()
{
    while (!shutdown)
    {
        suspendEvent.WaitOne();

        if (shutdown)
        {
            break;
        }

        Notify("Cleaning started!");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Notify("Cleaning finished!");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

When updating the UI it might also be necessary to invoke the `PropertyChanged` handler in the UI thread:

```
public string CleanerStatus
{
    get { return cleanerStatus; }
    set
    {
        cleanerStatus = value;
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new Action(() => OnPropertyChanged("CleanerStatus")));
    }
}
```

Comment: The rest of the handles are needed to control the behaviour of the Cleaner, but of course i will need to refactor that somehow. Your solution did not work unfortunately, the behaviour is the same. I found that OnPropertyChanged is called from the Cleaner thread, so that might be the problem.

Comment: It works fine for me. And I already addressed the fact that OnPropertyChanged is called from the background thread.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! The cause was a really silly mistake, I wont even mention what it was because it is awefully dumb. Your solution works great, thanks again.